# JS function argument undefined, even though it is

Tags: node.js, function, arguments

I'm having a very strange error on my registration function.

i want users to be able to register normally.
then i want to have a "register admin" page, which is only used to register one admin in the db.

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
   res.render('register', {title: "Register"});
});
router.post('/register', function registerUser(req, res) {
    validate.validateRegistration(req.body, res);
});

router.get('/registeradmin', function (req, res) {                                                          
    res.render('register', {title: "Register ADMIN"});                                                        
});         
router.post('/registeradmin', function(req, res) {   
    validate.validateRegistration(req.body, res, 'admin');  
});
```

as you may have noticed, for registering an admin, i pass 'admin' as third argument, which i supposed to be saved as user role. if there is no argument, it should be saved as 'student'

```
module.exports.validateRegistration = function(data, res, usrRole) {

console.log("validating");

console.log('role: ' + usrRole);

var username = data.username;
var password = data.password;
var email = data.email;
var firstname = data.firstname;
var lastname = data.lastname;
var role = usrRole || 'student';

// validation stuff here
}
```

that's pretty much everything.

## BUT

usrRole is undefined
and i have no idea why.
this is pretty much the most trivial error i've ever had and i feel stupid for asking, yet i have no idea why it is.

registering normal users works fine.
registering admins inserts 'student' as role in the DB, and the `console.log` says:

```
validate called
role: undefined
```

any ideas?
this SHOULD work, or am i blind?

Comment: Are you sure when registering admin you are calling registeradmin route, not register route?

Comment: Debug your code and be sure that you are calling registeradmin route. You can add console.log("bla bla"); to be sure that you are calling this route.

Comment: AWWW damn. thanks guys.
i had forgotten the form POSTing to '/register'. made another template that POSTs to '/registeradmin', now it works. thanks :)

Comment: Then I post my comment as an answer, maybe in the future somebody faced with same problem )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug your code and be sure that you are calling registeradmin route. You can add `console.log("bla bla");` to inside your registeradmin route to be sure that you are calling this route.